# item not found in create server console

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I would like to create `server console`. It has the below error.

```
{"itemNotFound":{"code":404,"message":"The resource could not be found."}
```

I send request to `:8774/v2.1/servers/e445.../remote-consoles`. The method is `POST`. The header contains `Content-Type: application/json` and `X-Auth-Token: admin_token`.

**Input**

```
{"remote_console":{"protocol":"vnc","type":"novnc"}}
```

My current version is `2.87`,with min_version `2.1`.

Comment: The API reference is not clear under which circumstances a 404 is generated. The server e445... might not exist, but perhaps VNC is not supported (would surprise me, but who knows). Perhaps the API request works when omitting `protocol` or `type`. I would try the CLI: `openstack --debug console url show e445...`. It displays the API requests it makes.

Comment: And of course, you could check the Nova API log, especially after enabling debug logging.

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks a lot. My problem was solved. According to the requests in the CLI, I should send the request to `:8774/v2.1/servers/e445.../action`.